# ANSIBLE - How to generate a list of "list entries" by using with_items and an inventory group

Tags: ansible

i am trying to generate a list of 'list-entries' by using with_items and the list of hosts of a certain inventory group. For example:

If i have two hosts in the inventory

```
[myservice]
 10.0.0.1
 10.0.0.2
```

then i want to create a yaml list by doing the following

```
service_clients:
- connection_type: "local"
  database: "all"
  user: "bob"
  address:"127.0.0.1/32"
- connection_type: "host"
  database: "all"
  user: "all"
  address: "::1/128"
- connection_type: "host"
  database: "myservicedb"
  user: "all"
  address: "{{ item }}/24"
  with_items: "{{groups['myservice']}}"
```

Nevertheless, the above fails. I am not able to iterate over the hosts list and create the X, for this example two, new elements.
How can i make this work?

Thank you in advance,
ioigoume

Answer (score 0):

You have a very fuzzy request. For a simple configuration file I'd say you need to use `{% for %}` feature of Jinja. For a specific type of iteration (just join them by coma), it's possible to use `|join()` filter of Jinja.

But you've asked for a way to create a list by means of `with_items`.

Here it is, a way to construct a list with `with_items`:

```
- name: Processing list
   set_fact:
      my_new_list: '{{ my_new_list|default([]) + [item] }}'
  with_items: '{{ groups.myservice }}'
```

I hope it would help, but I really thing you need to clarify your request.